# Fedora 21 VT Change Hangs

Tags: tty, logind

On Fedora 21, I have LightDM and i3 installed. When I switch to `tty2` and do a bit of work then switch back, my laptop hangs.

I am using Intel HD Graphics 4600.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE** now it sometimes happens when running my display manager and also if I have run `systemctl stop lightdm.service`

Comment: could you check your version of xorg-x11-drv-intel. Accortding to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1186178) if you update to xorg-x11-drv-intel 2.99.916 3.20141117.fc21 it is fixed.

Comment: I have xorg-x11-drv-intel 2.99.916 3.20141117.fc21 but I don't know if it happened in the distro-sync following the question. But I have done distro-sync after 20141117

Comment: @taliezin I want you to take the credit, so write an answer 'cos it seems fixed!

Comment: not a problem, it is not an answer by the rules of Unix & Linux Exchange, and it was just an asumption. I am happy it works. :)

Comment: I don't know if this is it or if it were something else. I regularly distro-sync but I think this was the first time I saw xorg-x11-drv-intel. Thanks!

Comment: actually i think it may still be happening :(

Comment: I am really sorry, if I find something will write you.